# How to check if an element from props matches a condition?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here I've made **inCart** condition which checks for the specific item existence in the cart but consequence is always true. What should I do instead?
(second **productId** is already given)

```
      let inCart = () => {
        props.cart.forEach(product => {
          if (product.productId === productId) {
            return true;
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        });
      };
      inCart
        ? console.log("Was returned TRUE!")
        : console.log("Was returned FALSE!!!");
```

Comment: `product.productId === productId`, where is the second `productId` comming from ??

Comment: It is already given by condition.

Comment: Change it to `inCart() ? console.log...`

Comment: Your `props.cart.forEach()` is running till `cart.length` times and in some condition,  `product.productId === productId`. thats why it returns true always. Can you share your `productID` and `products` array ??

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry now it's ok. Thank U!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It returns `true` because `inCart` is defined but you don't call it.

If you call it, it returns `undefined` which is falsy. Try this instead.

```js
let inCart = () => {
  return props.cart.some(product => product.productId === productId);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are just missing executing your function `inCart`.

Change this to

```
inCart()
  ? console.log("Was returned TRUE!")
  : console.log("Was returned FALSE!!!");
```

Without executing the function, you are basically just saying "if I have a function"

Answer (score 0):

You're definitely missing the call, but also your function needs a slight edit.

You can't return a value within a `forEach` or `map` function - what you want to do is set a boolean variable, and then return that once you've iterated through the array.

```
const inCart = () => {
  let foundProduct = false;

  cart.forEach(product => {
    if (product.productId == productId) {
      foundProduct = true;
    }
  });

  return foundProduct;
};

    inCart()
        ? console.log("Was returned TRUE!")
        : console.log("Was returned FALSE!!!");
```